# TypeError: pictures.forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display image slider on click.(slider working but pictures are not able to see in it)
Onclick of an image I am calling  a`toggleLightBoxView` function.
but getting this error

```
TypeError: pictures.forEach is not a function
toggleLightBoxView
src/Components/PreviewReport.js:145
  142 | const picContent =[];
  143 | const toggleLightBoxView = (pictures,pindex) =>{
  144 |   console.log(pictures)
> 145 |    pictures.forEach(ele => {
      | ^  146 |           if(ele.includes('.')) {
  147 |               picContent.push({
  148 |                   url: url+'/'+ele,
```

and I am unable to pictures in slider on click.
Kindly help to fix this error.

Here is my function that I call image onClick

```
      import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
        import ReactImageVideoLightbox from 'react-image-video-lightbox';
        const PreviewReport = (props) => {
        const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(true);
        const [lightBoxMedia, setLightBoxMedia] = useState([]);
        const [mediaImages, setmediaImages] = useState([]);
        const [showLightBox, setShowLightBox] = useState(false);
        const [currIndx, setCurrentIndx] = useState(0);
        const [mediaImages, setmediaImages] = useState([]);
        
        
       const picContent =[];
      const toggleLightBoxView = (pictures,pindex) =>{
console.log(pictures)#result displayed below
         pictures.forEach(ele => {
                if(ele.includes('.')) {
                    picContent.push({
                        url: url+'/'+ele,
                        type: 'photo',
                        altTag: 'House  details - '+ele
                    });
                } else {
                    picContent.push({
                        url: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/${ele}`,
                        type: 'video',
                        title: ' Details Video'
                    })
                }
            })
        
        console.log("pictures_with_url",picContent)
        setmediaImages(picContent)
        console.log("pindex",pindex)
        setCurrentIndx(pindex);
        setShowLightBox(!showLightBox);
    }
        
        return (
        <>
        {showLoader ? <Preloader flag={!showLoader} /> : ""}
        { showLightBox ?  
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", position: "fixed", zIndex: "9" }}>
        <ReactImageVideoLightbox data={mediaImages} startIndex={currIndx} showResourceCount={true} onCloseCallback={() => toggleLightBoxView(currIndx)} />
        </div>
        : ""} 
        
        {previewItemList.map((result,index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} data-index={index}>
            {result.pictures.length > 0
            ? result.pictures.map(
              (pictures, pindex) => {
              return (
                  <div
                  key={pindex}
                  className="preview-image"
                  >
                  <img
                  src={`${url}/${pictures}`}
                  alt={pictures}
                  onClick={() => toggleLightBoxView(result.pictures,pindex)}
                  />
                  </div>
              );
              }
            )
            : ""}
        );
        };
        
        export default PreviewReport;
```

Console result for pictures and pictures with url array.

```
pictures = [
    "IMG_0856.JPG",
    "IMG_0831.JPG",
    "IMG_0848.JPG"
]


pictures_with_url =[
{
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/reports/0413/YvQ0F5h6M80vWWWkewu3mPRb/juTxhlvBsTMaXPPcJmlq/IMG_0856.JPG",
    "type": "photo",
    "altTag": "House details - IMG_0856.JPG"
},
{
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/reports/0413/YvQ0F5h6M80vWWWkewu3mPRb/juTxhlvBsTMaXPPcJmlq/IMG_0831.JPG",
    "type": "photo",
    "altTag": "House details - IMG_0831.JPG"
},
{
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/reports/0413/YvQ0F5h6M80vWWWkewu3mPRb/juTxhlvBsTMaXPPcJmlq/IMG_0848.JPG",
    "type": "photo",
    "altTag": "House details - IMG_0848.JPG"
}
```

]

Comment: toggleLightBoxView has been called from two different places, the one that is being called from ReactImageVideoLightbox only passes index as an argument to toggleLightBoxView function which is an integer and whenever the toggleLightBoxView is called in this way, it should throw an error because you are trying to use the map on a number and not an array. Could you please verify if this is the issue.

Comment: I am calling `toggleLightBoxView` only one time, for  image click to view as a slider

Comment: Could you please check onCloseCallback prop of ReactImageVideoLightbox?

Comment: in `onCloseCallback` this function you are pass the only one parameter `toggleLightBoxView(currIndx)}`

Comment: solved the issue, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mediaImages` array look like this !

```
mediaImages={[
    {
      url: "https://placekitten.com/450/300",
      type: "photo",
      altTag: "some image",
    },
    {
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScMzIvxBSi4",
      type: "video",
      title: "some video",
    },
    {
      url: "https://placekitten.com/550/500",
      type: "photo",
      altTag: "some other image",
    },
    {
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScMzIvxBSi4",
      type: "video",
      title: "some other video",
    },
  ]}
```

currently you push only image url !

For more help [Click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-video-lightbox)

Comment: After adding this i can see the image , but still after i close the slider iIam getting the same error message, Pictures.map is not a function.

Comment: updated my answer. Any idea why I am getting this error still?

Comment: when `onCloseCallback` call you need to pass image array in  `toggleLightBoxView` this function !

currently you pass only `toggleLightBoxView(currIndx)` this.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using typescript.
when you are defined type for `toggleLightBoxView` arguments is still having trouble ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).